# Laravel one of mail sending jobs do not work

Tags: laravel, lumen

I have 3 different jobs that are pushed to queue to send mail (News, Welcome, ResetPassword).

News and Welcome works fine, so I created last one identically but it throws error in **storage/framework/views** that the variables I am sending are undefined, which is not true because I did dd() before dispatch() to see if variables are set.

I am using queue with database driver and supervisor

Controller:

```
public function sendRecoverLink(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email'
    ]);
    $user = User::where([
        'email' => $request->email,
    ])->first();

    if (! $user){
        return response(['Message' => "No such user"], 403);
    }

    $url = URL::current();    //some url as example
    //token crypting and inserting to database

    dispatch(new SendResetEmail($user, $url)); //sends mail


   return response(['message' => 'Send'], 200);
}
```

Job class

```
class SendResetEmail extends Job 
{
    protected $user;
    protected $url;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user, $url)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Mail::to($this->user->email)->send(new Reset($this->user->first_name, $url));
    }
}
```

Mail class

```
class Reset extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $user;
    protected $url;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user, $url)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.reset')
                    ->with([
                        'name' => $this->user->first_name,
                        'link' => $this->url,
                    ]);
    }
}
```

view

```
@component('mail::message')
# {{$name}}, 
    reset your password by clicking this link{{$link}}
@endcomponent
```

Error in database

```
ErrorException: Undefined variable: user in /var/www/eventmanager/storage/framework/views/03cb8c67266d078a3839b8266816206d466825f2.php:2
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/eventmanager/storage/framework/views/03cb8c67266d078a3839b8266816206d466825f2.php(2): Laravel\Lumen\Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}(8, 'Undefined varia...', '/var/www/eventm...', 2, Array)
#1 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/view/Engines/PhpEngine.php(43): include('/var/www/eventm...')
#2 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/view/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(59): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/var/www/eventm...', Array)
#3 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/view/View.php(137): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->get('/var/www/eventm...', Array)
#4 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/view/View.php(120): Illuminate\View\View->getContents()
#5 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/view/View.php(85): Illuminate\View\View->renderContents()
#6 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/mail/Markdown.php(61): Illuminate\View\View->render()
#7 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/mail/Mailable.php(217): Illuminate\Mail\Markdown->render('emails.reset', Array)
#8 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/mail/Mailable.php(189): Illuminate\Mail\Mailable->buildMarkdownView()
#9 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/mail/Mailable.php(119): Illuminate\Mail\Mailable->buildView()
#10 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/mail/Mailer.php(250): Illuminate\Mail\Mailable->send(Object(Illuminate\Mail\Mailer))
#11 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/mail/Mailer.php(205): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->sendMailable(Object(App\Mail\Reset))
#12 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/mail/PendingMail.php(99): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->send(Object(App\Mail\Reset))
#13 /var/www/eventmanager/app/Jobs/SendResetEmail.php(28): Illuminate\Mail\PendingMail->send(Object(App\Mail\Reset))
#14 [internal function]: App\Jobs\SendResetEmail->handle()
#15 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#16 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#17 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#18 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(549): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#19 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/bus/Dispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#20 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(114): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Bus\{closure}(Object(App\Jobs\SendResetEmail))
#21 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(App\Jobs\SendResetEmail))
#22 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/bus/Dispatcher.php(98): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#23 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(49): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->dispatchNow(Object(App\Jobs\SendResetEmail), false)
#24 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/queue/Jobs/Job.php(76): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->call(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Array)
#25 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/queue/Worker.php(320): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire()
#26 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/queue/Worker.php(270): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#27 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/queue/Worker.php(114): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), 'database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#28 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(101): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon('database', 'default', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#29 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(85): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'default')
#30 [internal function]: Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->handle()
#31 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#32 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#33 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#34 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(549): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#35 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/console/Command.php(183): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#36 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(252): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#37 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/console/Command.php(170): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#38 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(946): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#39 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(248): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#40 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(148): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#41 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/console/Application.php(88): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#42 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Console/Kernel.php(84): Illuminate\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#43 /var/www/eventmanager/artisan(35): Laravel\Lumen\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#44 {main}

Next ErrorException: Undefined variable: user (View: /var/www/eventmanager/resources/views/emails/reset.blade.php) in /var/www/eventmanager/storage/framework/views/03cb8c67266d078a3839b8266816206d466825f2.php:2
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/view/Engines/PhpEngine.php(45): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->handleViewException(Object(ErrorException), 0)
#1 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/view/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(59): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/var/www/eventm...', Array)
#2 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/view/View.php(137): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->get('/var/www/eventm...', Array)
#3 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/view/View.php(120): Illuminate\View\View->getContents()
#4 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/view/View.php(85): Illuminate\View\View->renderContents()
#5 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/mail/Markdown.php(61): Illuminate\View\View->render()
#6 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/mail/Mailable.php(217): Illuminate\Mail\Markdown->render('emails.reset', Array)
#7 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/mail/Mailable.php(189): Illuminate\Mail\Mailable->buildMarkdownView()
#8 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/mail/Mailable.php(119): Illuminate\Mail\Mailable->buildView()
#9 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/mail/Mailer.php(250): Illuminate\Mail\Mailable->send(Object(Illuminate\Mail\Mailer))
#10 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/mail/Mailer.php(205): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->sendMailable(Object(App\Mail\Reset))
#11 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/mail/PendingMail.php(99): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->send(Object(App\Mail\Reset))
#12 /var/www/eventmanager/app/Jobs/SendResetEmail.php(28): Illuminate\Mail\PendingMail->send(Object(App\Mail\Reset))
#13 [internal function]: App\Jobs\SendResetEmail->handle()
#14 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#15 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#16 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#17 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(549): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#18 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/bus/Dispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#19 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(114): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Bus\{closure}(Object(App\Jobs\SendResetEmail))
#20 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(App\Jobs\SendResetEmail))
#21 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/bus/Dispatcher.php(98): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#22 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(49): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->dispatchNow(Object(App\Jobs\SendResetEmail), false)
#23 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/queue/Jobs/Job.php(76): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->call(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Array)
#24 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/queue/Worker.php(320): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire()
#25 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/queue/Worker.php(270): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#26 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/queue/Worker.php(114): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), 'database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#27 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(101): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon('database', 'default', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#28 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(85): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'default')
#29 [internal function]: Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->handle()
#30 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#31 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#32 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#33 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(549): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#34 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/console/Command.php(183): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#35 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(252): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#36 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/console/Command.php(170): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#37 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(946): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#38 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(248): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#39 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(148): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#40 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/illuminate/console/Application.php(88): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#41 /var/www/eventmanager/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Console/Kernel.php(84): Illuminate\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#42 /var/www/eventmanager/artisan(35): Laravel\Lumen\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#43 {main}
```

Comment: Can you add the full error that you get.

Comment: @TheFallen added

Comment: If **emails.reset** is truly the view which you added to your question, then you need to run `php artisan view:clear` to clear the old view or restart your queue worker.

Comment: @TheFallen I am sorry for the late reply. Yes the view is `emails.reset`, I am using lumen, there is no command to clear views. Tried deleting the view in storage manually but that did no good.

Comment: For some reason it runs my old code, now I get error in `SendResetEmail.php` job with error undefined variable at line 31. Which I changed  some time ago. Tried doing `php artisan cache:clear` and `composer dump-autoload` still no good.

Answer (score 2):

Queue was running old code for some reason, what I had to do was `php artisan queue:restart` and it was fixed